# How do you Mock IUnityContainer?

Tags: c#, tdd, mocking, moq, unity-container

I'm trying to Mock the IUnityContainer using Moq 3.0

I'm getting a BadImageFormatException, but not when debugging. From the looks of it I'm not the only one that's ran into this problem.

[here](http://www.nabble.com/BadImageFormatException,-but-not-when-debugging-td18742529.html)

And its a registered issue for Moq

[here](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=87)

I'm just curious if anyone has found a solution... closest I've found is a nice solution that uses RhinoMock by Roy Osherove

[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2008/04/14/creating-a-automockingcontainer-with-microsoft-unity-pretty-darn-simple.aspx)

but I really like Moq! So I don't really want to have to switch to Rhino Mock but I will if I must

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Please let me know, if you found a solution to this.

Comment: So, are there no any solution still ? I've encountered the same issue with 3.1 Moq on 3.5sp1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

The only reason to mock the container is if you're passing it around. That's an anti-pattern.

Instead you want to compose the entire object graph at the application's entry point, or [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

If you need to create instances on the fly, use [Automatic Factories](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/using-unitys-automatic-factories-to-lazy-load-expensive-dependencies).

For your tests, you can either construct the object under test and pass mock objects to the constructor or create a new container in the test and register mock objects with it.

Comment: Agreed, made this question when I was young and nieve... I was also using IoC containers wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a full-blown mock object? Could you get by with simply implementing a Fake? I.e., implementing a test instantiation of the IUnityContainer interface and overriding the method that you need to interact with?

I've fallen into the trap more than once in thinking that since I have a mock object library, I should use it for isolating every dependency in my system. More often than not, doing something simpler gets me the results I want with much lower frustration levels.

Comment: Why has been this comment down voted? Those who down voted pls care to leave a note so that others who follow will be able to learn better from SO.

Comment: Indeed.  I upvoted the compensate.  Creating a stub would solve the issue by avoiding it entirely (no use of Moq needed).  It's a legit workaround and for those that voted this down, I'd encourage you to share why for the rest of the class.

Comment: Maybe Stackoverflowers don't like people with certifications? :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mocking UnityBaseContainer or UnityContainer instead of IUnityContainer, ala [this post](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2009/08/07/Mocking-IUnityContainer-and-avoiding-BadImageFormatException.aspx) by Rory Primrose?  He is dealing with RhinoMocks but because I think the issue is related to Moq's internal use of Castle, you may be able to solve the problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this problem I don't mock `IUnityContainer`, I use a real instance of `UnityContainer` instead. It's not ideal but I can test registration by checking that the container can resolve types as appropriate.

You can mock and use `IServiceLocator` when you're using it to resolve types in your classes, or even better, use register a factory with the container and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on Win x64 ? Have a look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx). It clearly suggests.

> ***This exception is thrown when the file format of a dynamic link library (.dll file) or an executable (.exe file) does not conform to the format that is expected by the common language runtime.***

Also, found this blog entry which suggests changing the compilation flag from Any CPU to x86 might help the cause. http://filips.net/archives/2008/01/17/getting-badimageformatexception-in-64-bit-windows/

**Edit:**

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-pl) SO thread. Have a look within your Build Configuration Manager as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to mock IUnityContainer's methods I would suggest mocking the methods on the interface rather than the extension methods.
People usually want to mock Resolve<TFrom, TTo> extension method which is not possible using Moq. Instead of mocking this method try mocking the one which is basically doing the job:

```
Mock<IMyInterface> myInterface = new Mock<IMyInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
Mock<IUnityContainer> containerMock = new Mock<IUnityContainer>(MockBehavior.Strict);
containerMock.Setup(c => c.Resolve(typeof(IMyInterface), null).Returns(myInterface.Object);
```

Here I mocked the non-generic Resolve function because it will be actually called by the generic one.