# C# - WCF - Serializing external classes

Tags: asp.net, wcf, serialization

I was receiving a "cannot serialize type..." error while attempting to serialize a BindingList. My initial thought was that the collection was the problem. I bypassed the collection and attempted to return a single instance of the class...same error. The classes are contained in a seperate project (but in the same solution); my next move was to copy and paste the class from the external project into the WCF project. With no other changes, the object now serializes.

Is this a namespace or persmissions issue? I can't rearchitect the solution at this point. What would prevent the class from seralizing in another project with the same code?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the full exception details (i.e. exception.ToString())please?

Comment: Did you add the Serializable attribute to the class? Still doesn't explain why it worked when you ported it over, but I'm curious.

Comment: When I was returning a BindingList of objects, my BindingList was marked as Serializable `[Serializable]
    public class BindingListBase<T> : BindingList<T>` The individual class (before and after moving) is marked as  ` [DataContractAttribute]  [DataContractAttribute]
    public class ICAddress : INotifyPropertyChanged, IObject `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was to simply recreate the WCF solution and add the class library projects to it. I have no idea what the problem was. Maybe bad meta information or something.

Answer (score 0):

Often when we get this error there is a sub class that does not have the Serializable or DataContract / DataMember attribute.

What is the class that you are using as T? Is that class marked as serializable?

**Edit**

For the error in the comment see ["An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" even when the platforms are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-pl)

Comment: No, it wasn't. It was just marked as [DataContractAttribute]. But it works as so when ported; standalone and as part of a BindingList collection. I noticed that my references were assembly refs so I blew them away and re-added them as project references. Now I get the message "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".  Everything is set to compile to 64bit.

Comment: Everything is building to 64 bit. I blew away the bin and obj folders for all projects and rebuilt. All IIS app pools are set to allow 32 bit applications. Same error...