# Importing a dll file written in C or C#

Tags: c#, c, dll

I am trying to import a .dll file which is written in C to Microsoft Visual C# Studio 2010?

Any ideas why I keep on getting this error?

> Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly prompt.

Comment: Try performing the step in this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647930/c-sharp-dll-run-time-error-builds-runs-but-throws-unhandled-exception-upon-t

Comment: @DorCohen That pre-supposes the existence of a managed assembly that wraps the native DLL

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import a reference to a native DLL. Instead you need to use p/invoke to import each function one by one. This can be a rather laborious process if you have a lot of functions so sometimes a C++/CLI wrapper is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're not using the `DllImportAttribute` correctly (or at all). See here:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx