# Reference shell32.dll in a programmatically compiled program?

Tags: c#, shell32

I need shell32 in my program to create a shortcut.

This is my code:

```
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var Params = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
{
      GenerateExecutable = true,
      OutputAssembly = outputName,
      ReferencedAssemblies = {
                    "System.dll",
                    "System.Core.dll",
                    "System.Windows.Forms.dll",
                    "System.Drawing.dll",
                    @"C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll"
 }
};
```

Doing this, I get an error:

> Metadata file C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll could not be opened. An attempt was made to load a program with incorrect format.

Found nothing while searching.. I wasn't even sure what to search for :/

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but `Shell32.dll` should be `shell32.dll` (Lowercase) Also might want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2024978/1218281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell32.dll (Windows file systems don't care about case, so "s" or "S" shouldn't matter) is not a .NET assembly and thus can't be treated as such.

If you want to call functions exported from non-.NET libraries, you should use the [`DllImportAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx).

Comment: This is what I need to do: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146757/Add-Remove-Startup-Folder-Shortcut-to-Your-App

However, I can't add references like it is shown there. I need to do it programatically. I don't understand how I'd go about using DllImport.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just solved it.

Add the following to your referenced Assemblies list:

```
    ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Interop.Shell32.dll");
```