# Could not load "Aurigma Graphicsmill", load program in incorrect format

Tags: visual-studio-2012, badimageformatexception, aurigma

## Not able to run as web-site in visual studio 2013

#### Could not load file or assembly 'Aurigma.GraphicsMill' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

#### Exception Details:

> **System.BadImageFormatException:** Could not load file or assembly **'Aurigma.GraphicsMill'** or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

```
 
 Stack Trace: [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Aurigma.GraphicsMill' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +416
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +166
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +190
```

Tried as suggested by *Graphicsmill* frequent asked questions forums for  *Web Application*

#### How to Resolve BadImageFormatException. (http://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/frequently-asked-questions.htm)

Any other *suggestions to make web-site run in my local-machine through visual studio 2013*  is really helpful.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to make the change to relevant application pool. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer, need to change to  **Relevant Application Pool.**

[["An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" even when the platforms are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p?rq=1])

Answered by  **Kalyan.**

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of information about this problem. Most of it is about a problem with 64-bit vs 32-bit. Well, my exact problem was I was using 64-bit Aurigma.GraphicsMill but my App pool (DefaultAppPool) had **Enable 32-Bit Applications** set to **True** which if you read the description on the bottom of the window says it makes your app run in 32-bit Mode. I was trying to run a 64-bit .dll from a 32-bit application.

[image]

Comment: For IIS Express: Go to: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects > Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express