# IIS is not installing in server

Tags: iis, wix, burn

I am installing IIS using wix burn which works fine in my local. When I am trying to install in server it's getting failed to install, and the error is **an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format**.

```
<!--Check For IIS Existance-->
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="IISWebServerRole64"
                         Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components"
                         Value="W3SVC"
                         Variable="WebServerRole"
                         Win64="yes"/>
 <!--Installs IIS if already not installed-->
      <ExePackage Id="IIS_WebServerRole"
                  SourceFile="setup.bat"
                  InstallCondition="NOT WebServerRole"
                  DisplayName="Installing IIS: IIS-WebServerRole"
                  InstallCommand="dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole">
      </ExePackage>
```

The setup.bat file is a simple text file, containing %*.

Log File

```
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_WebServerRole, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_WebServer, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_CommonHttpFeatures, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_StaticContent, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_DefaultDocument, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_DirectoryBrowsing, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_HttpErrors, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_HttpRedirect, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ApplicationDevelopment, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_NetFxExtensibility, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ISAPIExtensions, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ASP, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ISAPIFilter, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ASPNET, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_HealthAndDiagnostics, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_HttpLogging, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_LoggingLibraries, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_RequestMonitor, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_HttpTracing, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_CustomLogging, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_Security, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_WindowsAuthentication, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_RequestFiltering, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_IPSecurity, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_Performance, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_HttpCompressionStatic, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_WebServerManagementTools, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ManagementConsole, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ManagementScriptingTools, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ManagementService, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_WindowsActivationService, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ProcessModel, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_NetFxEnvironment, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_ConfigurationAPI, state: Absent, cached: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:16:59]i101: Detected package: IIS_NetFx3, state: Absent, cached: None
[2398:0EE4][2019-08-06T19:17:04]e000: Error 0x8007000b: Process returned error: 0xb
[2398:0EE4][2019-08-06T19:17:04]e000: Error 0x8007000b: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:17:04]e000: Error 0x8007000b: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:17:04]i319: Applied execute package: IIS_WebServerRole, result: 0x8007000b, restart: None
[1AD8:1A88][2019-08-06T19:17:04]e000: Error 0x8007000b: Failed to execute EXE package.
```

Comment: [Please check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p) before looking at anything else. What is the hardware and OS platform of the server? [Direct link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4619327/129130).

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, i did tried this already not working in my case. And my OS platform is windows 8.1 pro x64 bit. @SteinÅsmul

Comment: This message can occur the application is run in Visual Studio installed on 64-bit OS with the TargetCPU = “Any CPU”.As a solution, you can try to explicitly specify TargetCPU = x86 in project settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help sir, @Jalpa Panchal.I had changed my configuration setting to **Mixed Platforms**. This worked for me.

Comment: you could post your solution as an answer and mark the post. This will help other people who face the same issue.