# Signing XML document with digital signatures exception

Tags: digital-signature, msdn

I have been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-sign-xml-documents-with-digital-signatures?redirectedfrom=MSDN) MSDN example and when I try to compile it, it throws this exception: `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)` everything seems to work fine until it reaches `xmlDoc.Load("test.xml");` part. I searched around for a while and can't find an answer.

Did I miss something? Does anyone know why this is coming up?

Comment: Do any of the answers at [“An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format” even when the platforms are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, not really. I have read that question before posting this. But I think my problem is not caused by 32-bit and 64-bit processes. It's coming up when I try to `Load()` the XML file into the `XmlDocument` file.

Comment: But I will try it with x86 just in case. Thanks for replying btw.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've posted an answer. And thanks, it works but I don't know as to why it is necessary to run it as x86 specifically though. Can you tell me why?

Comment: I have no idea. Especially as the code has already run `Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()` by that point. But maybe it doesn't load the assembly with the XML stuff in until it actually does something with it, and somehow it's trying to use a 32-bit assembly when it shouldn't. That's only speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `Platform target` in Properties -> Build as x86 rather than "any CPU" solves it.

Dunno why XML file needs to be loaded with 32-bit only tho.