# Click once deployment MS outlook addoin getting issue System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: sqlite, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, clickonce

I have built outlook add-in using Visual studio 2015 Professional Addition. And used Click once deployment to push to ftp location so that it can be auto updated when ever version change happens.
It was working fine from past 3 years.

Now I am using Visual Studio 2015 community addition to do some changes and when I am trying to push changes I am getting error as

```
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

I am using SQLlIte interop service and SQLLite3 database now it is not able to use that service.

Thanks in advance for the help

[image: project build settings]

Comment: If you change AnyCPU to the specific target format of the SQLite assembly you are using does it work?

Comment: No still same issue if I change 64/86 tried both also but still no luck

Comment: When exactly do you get the error?

Comment: I changed my laptop and using Visual Studio community addition from then I am facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to load a 32 bit dll into a 64 bit process (or the other way around). You may find the following similar threads helpful:

- [BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54937f87-c7d4-4182-a34c-1bfe52b4a83b/badimageformatexception-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-exception?forum=netfx64bit)
- ["An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" even when the platforms are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p)

Make sure that your add-in dependencies support x64 and x86 platforms. Remember that you can't load and run x86 assemblies in the x64 process (or x64 assemblies into x86 process).

Comment: I tried to download 64 bit sql.iterop.dll from 
https://nuget.info/packages/SQLite.Interop.dll/1.0.103 
And copied in 64 folder and try to re build same issue coming

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
I deleted old 86 and 64 dll and download latest one and build the deployment now it is working thank you soo much

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to post as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Initial build that was using 32 bit sql lite dll file.

Now I try to download and copy latest 64 and 86 SQLite.Interop.dll files into respective folders now it is working dll reference link

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Interop/
```