# Visual Studio 2022 SSRS Map report error "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, visual-studio-2022

Error from the map in SSRS Visual Studio 2022

[image: 1]

Comment: I am having the same problem. My best guess is that it is coming from the HTML render engine (a similar error is commonly given by IIS) and probably to do with some legacy 32-bit components not playing nicely with 64-bit components.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR - it seems that the most recent version of Visual Studio that works correctly with the SSRS Map component is 2019 32 bit (NB: 64 bit VS 2019 has the same bug as VS 2022!!!)

My understanding of the problem is as follows:

Visual Studio has some IIS libraries it runs locally to render your report (recall that SSRS server requires IIS to host reports - VS is emulating this locally). There are a few references to this same error message being thrown by IIS:
["An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" even when the platforms are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p)

The cause is a mis-match between 32-bit and 64-bit libraries. It seems that in making more of VS 2022 into 64-bit MS has broken the map component, which presumably still uses some 32-bit libraries. I saw the same error when I tried with VS 2019 64-bit.

I was able to make the map component work correctly using VS 2019 32-bit.

I have reported this as a bug in Visual Studio 2022:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-SQL-Server-Reporting/10179684?port=1025&fsid=5cf1bfea-5cd6-4bea-b937-236713eac465